# How to solve this? Use a bridge table?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, star-schema

I am designing a star schema and come across this problem. I have two dimension table - a Product (Key = Product Id) and a Customer (Key = Customer Id). In another table there are three fields - Business Unit, Product Id and Customer Id.In this table one Product id refers to many Business Units and many Customer Ids. My question is do i need to place the third table as a bridge table between Product Dim and Customer Dim? Or what should be a better way to solve this?

---

### Product Dim

Product ID
Product Name
....
....etc

---

### Customer_Dim

Customer_Id
Customer Name
Customer Type
.....etc

---

### Third Table

Business Unit
Product ID
Customer ID
.....etc

Right now i created the third table as Bridge table and joined with Product and Customer Dim. The third table will have Product_id and Customer_id as FKs and Business Unit as the attribute.
Is this the right approach?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Yes, you have to use the third table as a bridge table and to create two foreign keys toward the other tables.

Comment: So does the bridge table contains only FKs? In my case the bridge table has two FKs (product id, customer id) and couple of other attributes like Business unit etc. Is that a correct way or should i not include attributes in bridge table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is what's called a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relation. A product can be connected to many companies, and a company can be connection to many products.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. So in fact table do i need to bring both the FKs or only one?

Comment: @Arun.K: You need both foreign keys, otherwise you only have a connection between two tables and a table that is unrelated.

Comment: Can i have attributes in the bridge table apart from the FKs. Since i am using the third table as Bridge it has attributes like Business Unit etc

Comment: @Arun.K: Yes, you can. That would be data that applies to the relation.